# What kind of device id is used in Google Cloud Messaging for generating regID?

Tags: android

Android says:

"In other words, a registration ID is tied to a particular Android application running on a particular device"

Well, it uses the application id, got from package name in manifest - and somehow the device id - but what id exactly? I could not find aynthing about it. how does gcm define the particular android device? by what value?

Comment: It's not a standard thing you're likely to be able to reverse engineer, but probably along these lines: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the regID is a random value generated by Google. For security they souldn't give the generator algorithm.

Also, If I'm not wrong, the regID you've associated can change and your client will be advice for the change.

Comment: The regID does actually change when the app is uninstalled and reinstalled.

Comment: that was not really my question - yes the id itself could be random - but it is unique for a special device with a special app. What i want to know is what parameter google is using for declaring the uniqueness of a device?

Comment: Maybe the gmail account or the MAC?

Comment: Maybe :D Thats My question^^